# Consuming batch of message from pubsub with Spring

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

How to consume multiple messages from pubsub? This seems like a simple problem that should have simple solution but currently I can find easy way to consume batches of records from pubsub with `spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub`.

I'm using `spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub` to consume messages from pubsub and process them in spring boot application. My current setup is very simple I have `PubSubInboundChannelAdapter` and `ServiceActivator` that consumes records. After research I have found spring integration `Aggregators` but they didn't seem like a good way of doing this because it's not easy to propagate the acknowledgment downstream. Is there anything I'm missing? How can I consume batches of messages?

Answer (score 1):

The `PubSubInboundChannelAdapter` is based on the subscription to the topic. So, it is going to be a stream of messages and this `PubSubInboundChannelAdapter` reacts to each of them converting to the Spring Message and sending it downstream to the configured channel.
There is really no way to get a batch of messages during subscription.

Also you need to keep in mind that there is no something like `offset` in GCP Pub/Sub. You indeed should acknowledge every single message you consume from the Pub/Sub.

Although there is the way to pull a batch of messages at once, using `PubSubMessageSource`. The `messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(5);` does the trick, but this `PubSubMessageSource` still produces every message individually, so you would be able to (n)ack them independently.

You can, of course, leverage the feature `PubSubMessageSource` uses - `PubSubSubscriberOperations.pullAndConvert()`. See it's JavaDocs for more info:

```
/**
 * Pull a number of messages from a Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription and convert them to Spring messages with
 * the desired payload type.
 * @param subscription the subscription name
 * @param maxMessages the maximum number of pulled messages
 * @param returnImmediately returns immediately even if subscription doesn't contain enough
 * messages to satisfy {@code maxMessages}
 * @param payloadType the type to which the payload of the Pub/Sub messages should be converted
 * @param <T> the type of the payload
 * @return the list of received acknowledgeable messages
 * @since 1.1
 */
<T> List<ConvertedAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage<T>> pullAndConvert(String subscription, Integer maxMessages,
        Boolean returnImmediately, Class<T> payloadType);
```

So, this one looks like what you are looking for because you indeed are going to have a list of messages and each of them is a wrapper with (n)ack callbacks.

This API could be used in the custom `@InboundChannelAdapter` `MessageSource` or `Supplier` `@Bean` implementation.

But still: I don't see benefits of the whole batch processing since every message can be ack'ed individually not affecting all others.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below:

```
@Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "pubsubInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "3"))
    public MessageSource<Object> pubsubAdapter(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubMessageSource messageSource = new PubSubMessageSource(pubSubTemplate, "testSubscription");
        messageSource.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

`maxMessagesPerPoll` property determines how many messages will be polled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i recently had the same problem. Google spring pubsub library does not provide expected result. Even if MessageSource is used pubsub messages are pulled in batches but library allows to handle them only one by one.
Using pull api allowed my to resolve it.
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#unary_pull_code_samples
Downside of this approach is that one needs to provide code that triggers pull. (scheduler)